# Having a problem using switches in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm getting the error "A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type" in my code at the line,

```
switch (job_selecter.SelectedValue)
```

Here's my code:

```
    private void start()
    {
        switch (job_selecter.SelectedValue)
        {
            case 0:
                head_seal_label.Text = "Ravager's Seal: Head (8)";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Could anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What type is job_selector.SelectedValue ?

Comment: What type is job_selecter.SelectedValue?

Comment: What type is job_selecter.SelectedValue?

Comment: job_selecter is a combobox within visual studio that contains a bunch of strings. i don't know what type it is... i'm sorry. would it be a string?

Comment: Tangentially, the `Ravager's Seal` only gives a +16 bonus to Lightning Resistance; hardly worth the 23000 chaos shards it costs to purchase from Rupert the Freebooter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you really want to do is this:

```
switch(job_selecter.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        // do whatever
        break;

    default:
        // handle default case
        break;
}
```

You've noted in one of your responses that casting `SelectedValue` to `string` or `int` or whatever can cause a null reference exception if you then use it in a switch--which makes perfect sense, because it's perfectly legal for a combo box to have *nothing* selected, and you're going to need to account for that case.  If you switch on SelectedIndex, handling -1 will allow you to handle a case of "no selection" specifically.

Of course, it's worth pointing out that switching on `SelectedIndex` only makes sense if the combo box contains a *known, unchanging* set of values.  Adding or removing values will potentially cause the indices of everything in the box to change, thus breaking the switch.

Comment: Also, if the combo box's Sorted property is true, adding new items could screw up the indexing.

Answer (score 5):

`job_selecter.SelectedValue` is probably an object.

```
 private void start()
    {
        int index = (int)job_selecter.SelectedValue;
        switch (index )
        {
            case 0:
                head_seal_label.Text = "Ravager's Seal: Head (8)";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: oops, i accidentally responded to the wrong comment below. i added (int) as you said up above, but it told me i had a NullReferenceException was unhandled error. does that mean it wasn't the right type?

Comment: never mind. I missed a line you typed in, and it worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: okay, so now when i tried adding additional cases, i get the NullReferenceException was unhandled error again on the

int index = (int)job_selecter.SelectedValue;

line. Why is this?

Comment: @Ben it's because there is no selected value in the combobox when it evaluates that expression, or job_selecter itself is not set to an object (trying to reference a property such as `SelectedValue` of a NULL object results in a NullReferenceException)

Answer (score 2):

SelectedValue is an `object`. cast it to an `int` in the switch.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new at coding.

job_selecter is a combobox within Visual Studio. It contains a bunch of strings.

Comment: @Ben - I don't think there is any reason to be sorry; it's only easy when you know the answer.

Comment: i put (int) in front as you said, but it gave me another error when I compiled:

nullreferenceexception was unhandled

Answer (score 1):

You might have meant to use **"SelectedIndex"** property (a zero based number corresponding to your selection in combo OR a -1 when nothing is selected):

```
switch (job_selecter.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        head_seal_label.Text = "Ravager's Seal: Head (8)";
        break;
    // other cases for other Indices
    case -1:
    default:
        // handle nothing selected...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get your SelectedIndex into an int first, to deal with this error " "A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type" in my code at the line":

```
int index;
if(!Int32.TryParse(job_selector.SelectedIndex.ToString(), out index))
{
    index = -1;
}
//All your other cases here    
switch(index)
{
    case 0:
        head_seal_label.Text = "Ravager's Seal: Head (8)";
        break;

    default:
        head_seal_label.Text = "Some default Value";
        break;
}
```